# Why does not "call 12345678" jump to "12345678" address?

Tags: assembly

Simply, why does not `call 12345678` jump to `12345678` address?
Why do I have to use the instruction like this

```
mov eax, 12345678
call eax
```

More importantly, what does `call 12345678` exactly do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of call binary encoding. See the details and properties for intel processors at

[Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.html) at page 3-114 Vol. 2A for Intel architecture.
If you are talking about different processor, please state which exactly.

Comment: In the latest Intel Manual this page (3-114 Vol. 2A) refers to the `CLI` instruction documentation, however just a few pages back (3-96 Vol. 2A; Page 575-580) contains a complete treatment of `CALL` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`call 12345678` pushes the following instruction's return address onto the stack and then jumps to `12345678`.

It is functionally equivalent to:

```
mov eax, 12345678
call eax
```

(Though the code above has the side-effect of modifying `eax`, whereas a simple `call 12345678` does not modify `eax`.)

Comment: All variants of call with immediate operands are relative, which may lead to the problem described in the question. The only exception is 9a opcode which is not valid in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Yes, but @FreeMind was asking about the instruction (the "disassembly"), not the machine code.